# How to dynamically insert componenet in view?

Tags: iphone, ipad

[image: Demo image for this question]

this is demo image. I have to develop same type of dialog or view, is it programatically developed or is there an inbuilt  component?

1. Is there a predefined component in a library?
2. If not, then how is it possible and also I want delegate of the component
3. How to calculate downloadind time so it will become esy to calculate in progress view

Comment: *Please* run your questions through a spell checker before posting them. It helps you looking more professional, and helps us reading the question. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one method *addSubview* in *UIView* class. You can add any views inside the other view (or any class which is inherited by *UIView*).

Here as per your image, you can add *UIActivityIndicator*, *UIProgressBar* instances to *UIAlertView* by using that method only.

For that:

- Create one custom alertview class which subclasses with *UIAlertView*
- In the *init* method, add your additional views by setting its frame and other values
- Add subviews to self (custom alertview) instance

Now you are free to use your custom alert view any where.

Comment: is it possible to write the code for this i have created the custom alertview then how to add frame on custom alert view??

Comment: Refer this link: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Here they have added textfield, the same way you can add other UIControls as well

Comment: i want its value in delegate also i want how to calculate total downloading time of the file so progressbar will work effectively....

Comment: Then go with custom delegate, by writing your own protocol.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its not a predefined component.
2. You can use the predefined components and create the view using Labels, Activity indicators, Button. Check out [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) on github.

Comment: Downloading above file contain lost of error have you any idea for this??

Comment: Then you probably don't know how to use it. Its a very popular progress bar alternative out there.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading view is a custom progress view which contains uiactivityindicator too. It is programmatically created. Behind downloading view is a table view with two sections with header names Purchased stories and downloaded stories. The both views are programmatically created. You can use SVProgressHUD or MBProgressHud from git hub.
To get the time:-

```
UIProgressView *myProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
float someFloat = 0;

NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(methodToUpdateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: in downloading view how to calculate total time required for downloading in progress view